# Receive Magento Logo when getting product image

Tags: image, url, slider, placeholder

I am learning Magento and I am trying to create a slider which show products' images. I am ok with the JS slider but I have problem when trying to get product images. I have tried these codes:

```
<?php
$productModel = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$product_1 = $productModel->load(1);
$name = $product_1->getData('name');
$description = $product_1->getData('description');
echo $name . '<br/>';
echo $description . '<br/>';
echo $product_1->getImageUrl();
?>
```

The product's name and description are ok. But the image URL seems not right: http://hellomagento.dev/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/265x/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/images/catalog/product/placeholder/image.jpg
It's a Magento logo in gray color.

I have upload image for the product already.

Please help! Thank you!

Comment: Hi, can you please try with <?php echo Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($product_1, 'small_image')->resize(200); ?> here, 200 is image size.

Comment: Also check, have you assigned uploaded image to 'Small Image' from admin panel ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have selected the base, small and thumbnail options for your product image as shown below. The Magento logo in grey is a placeholder for a product with no images selected.

[image]

Comment: When I apply it for a collection, the same problem happened. This is my code: `<?php
       $product_collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->setOrder('name', 'asc'); 

      foreach($product_collection as $_product)
       {
           ?><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo  $_product->getName(); ?>"><?php echo $_product->getName(); ?> - </a><?php
           echo "Product ID: ";
           echo $_product->getId() . " - ";
           echo $_product->getImageUrl();
           echo "<br />";
       }
?>`

Comment: In your collection you need to specify the attributes you want to collect, i.e. for image url use ->addAttributeToSelect('image')